# time taken for smart group updating

Tags: smartgroups

How quickly should I expect my smart group to update?

I use smart groups to do calling from and data usually gets altered as a result of the call. However in order to get the the smart group contacts to update I have to clean the cache (or wait for the job to run).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

there is also a link at civicrm/group?reset=1 where you can 'update smart group counts' which uses this path /civicrm/group?reset=1&update_smart_groups=1 so you could probably put a Menu item in with that destination if it is something that you need to do frequently.

There is also a setting at civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1 where you can reduce the "Smart group cache timeout" (The number of minutes to cache smart group contacts. We strongly recommend that this value be greater than zero, since a value of zero means no caching at all. If your contact data changes frequently, you should set this value to at least 5 minutes.)